# 0.11.4 Touch seems off target in landscape orientation

Tags: ios-simulator, calabash, calabash-ios

Originally we had automated tests working and running continuously back in August. After a lapse they became out of date and we had to put them on hold. I'm trying to get them working again and after updating Calabash-ios, the calabash server, and the Calabash component to the Xamarin Cloud component I ran into a problem. The touch calls aren't working quite right anymore. It seems that the touch is off target.

For example: I try to touch the sign in button of our app and instead the "r" button on the keyboard gets pressed. The keyboard isn't covering the button either.

I've tried the workaround given [here](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/issues/528) thinking that maybe the landscape orientation is causing the problem but no luck.

This is using an iPad 2 simulator running iOS 8.1. I've also tried 7.1 and had the same issue. We are using Xamarin if that makes any difference.

Versions:

```
~$ xcode-select --print-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
~$ 
~$ xcodebuild -version
Xcode 6.1.1
Build version 6A2008a
~$ 
~$ calabash-ios version
0.11.4
~$ 
~$ curl http://localhost:37265/version

{
    "app_version": "Unknown",
    "outcome": "SUCCESS",
    "app_id": "com._______.dev",
    "simulator_device": "iPad",
    "version": "0.11.4",
    "app_name": "_____ Dev",
    "iphone_app_emulated_on_ipad": false,
    "4inch": false,
    "git": {
        "remote_origin": "git@github.com:calabash/calabash-ios-server.git",
        "branch": "master",
        "revision": "bcc992b"
    },
    "screen_dimensions": {
        "scale": 1,
        "width": 768,
        "sample": 1,
        "height": 1024
    },
    "iOS_version": "8.1",
    "system": "x86_64",
    "simulator": ""
 }
```

I can reproduce it from calabash-ios console as well.

Both of these commands click the "R" button on the digital keyboard:

```
irb(main):011:0> touch("button marked:'Sign In'")
[
    [0] {
           "selected" => false,
            "enabled" => true,
               "rect" => {
            "center_x" => 339.6667,
                   "y" => 341,
               "width" => 58,
                   "x" => 310.6667,
            "center_y" => 428,
              "height" => 174
        },
                 "id" => nil,
    "description" => "<UIButton: 0x78f80b00; frame = (509 310.667; 174 58); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x78f80ab0>>",
              "label" => "Sign In",
              "alpha" => 1,
              "class" => "UIButton",
              "frame" => {
                 "y" => 310.6667,
             "width" => 174,
                 "x" => 509,
            "height" => 58
        }
    }
]
irb(main):012:0> tap_point(339, 428)
```

Where as this command clicks the sign in button correctly:

```
irb(main):023:0> tap_point(639, 328)
true
```

Has anyone seen something like this before? Also, this doesn't happen when I use a physical device.

Answer (score 0):

> Has anyone seen something like this before? Also, this doesn't happen when I use a physical device.

Yes, we have had reports of problems like this and they have been, for the most part, resolved by the 0.12.0 pre-releases.

Can you try the following to reproduce:

```
$ DEVICE_TARGET="iPad Retina (8.1 Simulator)" bundle exec calabash-ios console
> start_test_server_in_background({ :uia_strategy => :host })
```

The :host strategy is slower than the :preferences strategy.  However, because of several bugs in Apple's UIAAutomation API, it is the only strategy that works on iOS 8 *devices*.

The 0.12.0 pre-releases contain significant improvements in the :host and :preferences strategies.  When 0.12.0 is released, you can drop the :uia_strategy => :host and stick with the recommended defaults.

The pre-release situation for UITest is improving; I believe that pre-releases are now available.  I don't know what the latest pre-release is.  I will inquire and update my answer.

Comment: I get the same outcome using that method but I'm not using bundler so the `bundle exec` was left out. Running the tests on a simulator isn't that important for us right now since we will primarily be testing on physical devices anyway. We can wait for 0.12.0 to be released and see if that fixes the problem.